# Rock Paper Scissors 2 player

Tags: python

Here is my code for my 2 player game. What I'm having trouble with is no matter what, player 2 always wins and gives points to player 2. Can someone help me make it so Player 1 can also win and be assigned points.

```
def vshuman():

score = [0,0]
    while True:

        while True:
            user1_choice = input("Player 1 choose a weapon (1,2,3,4)")
            user2_choice = input("Player 2 choose a weapon(1,2,3,4)")
            if user1_choice == "1":
                user1_choice == 1
                break
            if user2_choice == "1":
                user2_choice == 1
                break
            elif user1_choice == "2":
                user1_choice == 2
                break
            elif user2_choice == "2":
                user1_choice == 2
                break
            elif user1_choice == "3":
                user1_choice == 3
                break
            elif user2_choice == "3":
                user2_choice == 3
                break
            elif user1_choice == "4":
                user1_choice == 4
                main()
            elif user2_choice == "4":
                user1_choice == 4
                main()

        if user1_choice == user2_choice:
            print("Tie")
            score[0] = score[0] + 1
            score[1] = score[1] + 1
        elif (user1_choice == 1 and user2_choice == 3):
            print("Player 1 won")
            score[0] = score[0] + 1
        elif(user1_choice == 2 and user2_choice == 1):
            print("Player 1 won")
            score[0] = score[0] + 1
        elif(user1_choice == 3 and user2_choice == 2): 
            print("Player 1 won")
            score[0] = score[0] + 1
        elif(user2_choice == 1 and user1_choice == 3): 
            print("Player 2 won")
            score[1] = score[1] + 1
        elif(user2_choice == 2 and user1_choice == 1): 
            print("Player 2 won")
            score[1] = score[1] + 1
        elif(user2_choice == 3 and user1_choice == 2): 
            print("Player 2 won")
            score[1] = score[1] + 1



        while True:
            answer = input("Play another Round")
            if answer == "y" or "Y":
                print(" score: Player 1 -",score[0]," Player 2 -",score[1])

                break
            elif answer == "n" or "N":
                print("I hope you enjoyed! Final score Player 1 -",score[0]," Player 2 -",score[1])

                break
            else:
                print("y or n")
```

Comment: You're calling `main()` but never defining it. Please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh no I have Main in my full code this is just part of it I need help with

Comment: That is why @L3viathan is asking for an MVCE. We can't test the code ourselves and the question itself is *off-topic*. Questions seeking debugging help are not welcome

Comment: Also, I've never heard of a rock-paper-scissors variant with 4 (or any even number) kinds of weapons.

Comment: 4 is to  return to the main menu. Sorry if i'm causing problems i'm just confused on why it keeps makng player 2 win

Comment: Take a close look at your `if` constructs. Hint: `if player1 ... ELSEIF player2`.

Comment: `user1_choice == 4` You're never setting user1's choice, '==' is an equality test, not an assignment.  Try `user1_choice = 4`.

Answer (score 0):

```
score = [0,0]
while 1:
    c1 = int(input("Player 1 choose a weapon (1,2,3) : "))
    c2 = int(input("Player 2 choose a weapon (1,2,3) : "))
    if c1 == c2:
        print('tie')
        score[0] += 1
        score[1] += 1
    elif (c1 - 1) % 3 == c2 % 3:
        print('Player 1 won')
        score[0] += 1
    else :
        print('Player 2 won')
        score[1] += 1
    print(" score: Player 1 -",score[0]," Player 2 -",score[1])
    answer = input("Play another Round (y / n) : ")
    if answer.lower() != "y":
        break
```